# Why is TeraSort map phase spending significant time in CRC32.update() function?

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce, visualvm, crc32

I am trying to profile which functions consume the most time for a TeraSort Hadoop job. for my test system, I am using a basic 1-node pseudo-distributed setup. This means that the NameNode, DataNode, Tasktracker, and Jobtracker JVMs all run on the same machine.

I first generate ~9GB of data using TeraGen and then run the TeraSort on it. While the JVMs execute, I sample their execution using VisualVM. I know this is not the most accurate profiler out there, but it's free and easy to use! I use the latest version of Apache hadoop distribution, and my experiments are run on an Intel Atom based system.

When I look at the Self time (CPU) for Hot Spots-Methods in VisualVM, I see java.util.zip.CRC32.update() function taking up nearly 40% of total time. When I look at this function in the call tree, it's invoked by the main() function of the mapper, specifically when the IdentityMapper.map() is reading input files from the HDFS. The function that actually makes the call to CRC32.update() function is org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readChecksumChunk()

I have a three questions regarding this:

1. Why is CRC32 checksum being updated for blocks being read from the HDFS? If I understand correctly, once a block is read, a simple comparison of the data read from the disk with the block's CRC should be the only operation, not generating and updating the blocks CRC value.
2. I looked up the source for the update function, and it's implemented by the java.util.zip.CRC32.java file. The specific function called is the overloaded update() method with three arguments. Since this function is implemented in Java, is it possible that multiple layers of abstraction (Hadoop, JVM, CPU instructions) are reducing the native efficiency of CRC calculation?
3. Finally, is there something grossly wrong with my VisualVM instrumentation methodology, or interpretation of the sampling results?

Thanks,

Comment: Note that `CRC32.update()` is the main worker function for _computing_ a CRC, even if the only use of that computation is to compare its output with a known result.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, I think the answer is that the CRC files have replicas and can be corrupted. For example, assume we have a bunch of files/directories with replication factor of 2, then following scenarios can happen and CRC will need to be recalculated and updated:

1. Delete meta file on one replica
2. Truncates meta file on one replica
3. Corrupts the meta file header on one replica
4. Corrupts any random offset and portion of the meta file
5. Swaps two meta files, i.e the format of the meta files are valid but their CRCs do not match with their corresponding data blocks

If you take a look at the JIRA issues for Hadoop Common, you can find many issues related with CRC corruption.

For the second question, could you tell me which version of Hadoop are you using? The efficiency of CRC has been complained and improved again and again.

Comment: I just realize this question is posted in 2011. Answers may not be helpful now...